# How to make bootstrap nav bar scrollable via gesture?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-website

[image]

I have a nav bar as shown as above. It is done using twitter bootstrap. However, there is alot of button.

Is it possible to make the whole nav bar scroll-able(via touch gesture) to see more buttons? (eg. right and left scroilable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to apply this in your css:

```
.navscroll {
   overflow-x: scroll;
```

to your navbar giving you the horizontal scroll.